# Definition of the supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

If $M=\sup \left( A \right)$ and $A\subseteq  \mathbb{Q}$ (rational numbers)

$\forall\ \varepsilon>0$ of $\mathbb{Q}, \exists\ x\in A$ s.t. $x > M–\varepsilon$.

Is this property true for rationals ? because in Wikipedia $A$ always a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (real numbers)

That really confuse me.

Comment: "The [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of a subset $S$ of a partially ordered set $T$ is the least element in $T$ that is greater than or equal to all elements of $S$, if such an element exists. Consequently, the supremum is also referred to as the least upper bound. The infimum of a subset $S$ of a partially ordered set $T$, assuming it exists, does not necessarily belong to $S$. If it does, it is a *minimum* or least element of $S$."

Comment: What would be the consequence IF this statement was not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of supremum is valid in all kinds of underlying sets with an ordering relation $\leq$, so it also works in the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. The property you state there is also true there.

The only decisive difference is that in $\mathbb{R}$, every (bounded) set has a supremum. In $\mathbb{Q}$, you can construct many sets that do not have a supremum because that would be a number in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: About the last sentence, of course it's correct. However you may also want to mention that the supremum can be $\infty$. In which case we often say that the supremum doesn't exists.

Comment: Every bounded nonempty set has a supremum.